# jqGrid inline navigator urls

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

Playing with jqGrid now. And have some questions.

The thing i want to do is pretty simple. I created custom web service for CRUD operations. 
Using ajax request, i get JSON and bind it to specified jqGrid.

Now i want to use their new inline navigator to create new records and update existing. 
As i know, there is 'editurl' property to set the link for update. But it is also being used for adding items.

Is it possible to separate these urls for different actions and pass JSON with row data to my service? Or event better - in some kind of handler just create custom Ajax requests to the service?

Tried to use inlineNav add params, but managed to set handler for 'oneditfunc' only.

With forms editing there was no such problem. Maybe i have missed something?

**UPD:** managed to customize it using custom 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons, where i send needed request. But hope, there is much easier solution or not?

**UPD** My sample is available here: http://jqgridtest.cloudapp.net:8080/ In any case - add or delete, always only Edit method is being called. What am i doing wrong?

**UPD** The described problem with links has nothing common with cross-domain policies. When there is cross-domain issue - there are another errors like '405 Method not allowed' etc. Also the deployed sample service has a workaround for cross-domain requests. And yep, it won't work in IE, because in my client sample i didn't add `$.support.cors=true` to make it work in IE.
You can also check out here: http://jsbin.com/uxered/7/ There are relative urls Add and Edit there. But only Edit is being called.

Also the video proof of working with jqgridtest.cloudapp.net: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zivlvsV1r98&feature=youtu.be As you can see, the request is successful, so no cross-domain issues, but Edit url is called.

Answer (score 0):

The method [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#inlinenav) has `addParams` and `editParams` options. The method `addRow` has `addRowParams` option which can be used to specify options of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) used during adding rows. So the following parameters should work

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#pager", {
    addParams: {
        addRowParams: {
            keys: true,
            url: "/MyAddRowAction"
        }
    },
    editParams: {
        keys: true,
        url: "/MyEditRowAction"
    }
});
```

**UPDATED**: The error in your demo is very easy: you use `url:"http://jqgridtest.cloudapp.net:81/Service1.svc/web/AddData"` and `url:"http://jqgridtest.cloudapp.net:81/Service1.svc/web/EditData"` in the demo which works on `http://jqgridtest.cloudapp.net:8080/`. There are security restriction in Ajax known under the name [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You should include web service `Service1.svc` *in the same ASP.NET site* (just include in the same project). After that you will be able to use *relative* URL path like `url:"/Service1.svc/web/AddData"` and `url:"/Service1.svc/web/EditData"` and your code will work.

Comment: @sleepwalker: Sorry, but you made an error in the test. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/addRowParam2.htm). Because I don't have and server components under the URLs `/MyAddRowAction` and `/MyEditRowAction` one will see errors. Nevertheless using Fiddler, Firebug, Developer Tools and so on you can verify that  jqGrid post the data to `/MyAddRowAction` on adding of the new row and post the data to `/MyEditRowAction` of editing. So The settings which I suggested do work.

Comment: Yep, i've also looked through this demo already. Later will try once more.

Comment: @sleepwalker: Could you see that **different** URLs was used by the demo for Add and Edit operations?

Comment: My sample is available here: http://jqgridtest.cloudapp.net:8080/ In any case - add or delete, always only Edit method is being called. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @sleepwalker: Your error is very easy: see "UPDATED" part of my answer.

Comment: No, cross domain is not a problem here. The request to url:"http://jqgridtest.cloudapp.net:81/Service1.svc/web/EditData" is successful, but it is being sent in both: add and edit.

Comment: @sleepwalker: Sorry, but you should exactly test before you claim something. Your demo has do cross domain error in IE9, but in Developer Tools you can easy verify the *different* URL will be used for Add and Edit operations. In Chrome 20 you can also use Developer Tools and verify in Network tab that Add uses "http://jqgridtest.cloudapp.net:81/Service1.svc/web/AddData" URL and edit use URL "http://jqgridtest.cloudapp.net:81/Service1.svc/web/EditData". So your last comment is just wrong.

Comment: I always check everything before. And have tried lots of variants before posting this question to stackoverflow, including your variants. Have you checked the differences between the urls? Here is the small video: http://youtu.be/zivlvsV1r98

Comment: @sleepwalker: I can only repeat, that if I do **the same** I see `http://jqgridtest.cloudapp.net:81/Service1.svc/web/AddData` on "Add" operation. I can repeat one more time that the usage of different port is *wrong*. Please reread [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) the rules of the same origin policy.

Comment: @sleepwalker: See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddEditURLs.png) the screenshort.

Comment: Oleg, thanks for the help. I've already worked with cross-domain issues and had to use workarounds that always worked as know. In real life it happens that client and service are at different domains. So please, don't get me rid of these wiki links :) Be sure, that's not the issue talking about difference of links.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13251/discussion-between-sleepwalker-and-oleg)